# Maximum call stack size exceeded using mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm calling a function using a useEffect. If the data being fetched is an array the function is then parsed (https://github.com/reworkcss/css). However, this is causing the error with mobx. I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
    convertToRule(): void {
    var CSS = require('css');
    if (this.theme && this.theme.jsonStructure && this.theme.css) {
        const stylesheet = JSON.parse(
            this.theme.jsonStructure
        ) as Reptile.Models.IThemesStyling[];
        if (Array.isArray(stylesheet)) {
            this._rule = CSS.parse(this.theme.css);
        } else {
            this._rule = stylesheet;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have an infinite loop somewhere. You should share more of your code, I don't see the useEffect that you're referring to here.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        controller.convertToRule();
    }, [controller, controller.theme?.jsonStructure]);

Comment: That's the useEffect although I'm certain that it is not that and is in fact something to do with the css.parse/ makeObservable

Comment: Could you provide more code? For example, what is `this._rule`? Is it an observable?